# Distance Formula with if statements

Tags: java, android, distance

I am trying to use to distance formula, When I try to run the program, I can put in values for x1,y1,x2, but no result shows up when I try and find the distance. Any suggestions?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editText, editText2, editText3, editText4;
Button button;

TextView tv_result;

double a,b,c,d, e, x1,x2,y1,y2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    //tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText2.getText().toString().equals("")
                && !editText3.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText4.getText().toString().equals("")){

                x1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                x2 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                y1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                y2 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

                e = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+ Math.pow(y2-y1,2));

               // if (e == 0) {
                   // tv_result.setText("The two points are the same");
                  if (e > 0){
                    tv_result.setText("e");


                }






            }


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `//tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);` - is this line really commented out? That would mean `NullPointerException`. Also, change `tv_result.setText("e");` to `tv_result.setText(Double.toString(e));`

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question as clarity is missing  @Akshay

Answer (score 2):

Basically forked your code. Made some changes though.

**Changes**

1. Uncomment `tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);` as @ibtehaz pointed out as it would lead to an NPE at `tv_result.setText("e");`.
2. At this line `tv_result.setText("e");` you are setting the character "e" to the `TextView` rather than your result. You should be doing `tv_result.setText(e);`.

See complete code below,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText, editText2, editText3, editText4;
    Button button;

    TextView tv_result;

    double a,b,c,d, e, x1,x2,y1,y2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("") 
                    && !editText2.getText().toString().equals("")
                    && !editText3.getText().toString().equals("")
                    && !editText4.getText().toString().equals("")){

                        x1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                        x2 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                        y1 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                        y2 = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

                        e = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+ Math.pow(y2-y1,2));

                        if (e == 0) {
                            tv_result.setText("The two points are the same");
                        } else if (e > 0){
                            tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(e));
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume if answer commented line, he tried it when it was uncommented.

Comment: Much easier actually. 3 lines changed though. :)

Comment: `tv_result.setText(e);` - this line won't pass compilation.

Answer (score -1):

Change/ UN COMMENT THIS LINE

```
tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
```

You would have get an ERROR when you try to bind data on a NULL Object! 
Cheers!

Comment: You missed the actual issue here!